# SharePoint ashx handler file download Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, handler, binarywriter

I have a ashx handler that gets a file we are using, this in SharePoint, and then it checks what kind of file it is and then it writes using `Response.BinaryWrite`. It get this file from another server, that contains all of our files. When I go to download a file thats like 3MB it works fine. But when I go to download a 30MB or 40MB file I get the error.

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
```

I checked my Application Pool at we have it set at 1.5GB for Virtual and 1GB for actual memory. I am out of ideas and dont know where to go next does anyone have any ideas?

```
    case "PDF":
         context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
         context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + asset.A_Name);
    }

    context.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
```

Comment: Did you try upping max file size in web.Config of receiving server?

Comment: Hello op. How did you made this handler? I'm trying to make one work, following this article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2010/08/04/deploying-an-asp-net-httphandler-to-sharepoint-2010/) but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try Response.TransmitFile method, which does not buffer the content in server memory.

Comment: sorry the files are coming from another server that stores the files, this they have to be stored in memory. TransmitFile requires that the file be a path on that server.